# Hierarchy Attribute Evalutors in ArcPy (ArcGIS Indoors)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-enterprise, indoor

I am trying to edit the [Thin Indoor Pathways](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/indoors/thin-indoor-pathways.htm) tool to take into account pathway rankings when solving the network. I have built the network dataset from the Indoors template, edited it to use hierarchy, and mapped the hierarchy field evaluators. I then created a new template from the edited network dataset, and changed the tool script to reference that template instead of the default.

After running the tool, the results are the same as before. For example, thinned pathways are leaving hallways empty in favor of cutting through a large room in the center of the building, rather than going through the hallway. At the middle point of the building, the pathway between two adjacent rooms goes down separate hallways, and through the large room rather than connecting the hallway that connects the two rooms.

I looked in the network dataset properties and while it is using hierarchy, the field evaluators are not setup anymore.

So I'm trying to find a way to map the field evaluators properly within the script, but am having no luck combing through the ArcPy documentation. It seems that [network dataset properties](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/network-attributes.htm) are read-only, and the tool deletes and recreates the network dataset after verifying the inputs. It creates it using the following line:

```py
outputNDataset = arcpy.CreateNetworkDatasetFromTemplate_na(prelimNetworkTempatePath, featureDatasetPath)
```

I'm unsure what to do with the XML file, but here is the line that includes the hierarchy option:

```xml
<PropertySetProperty xsi:type="typens:PropertySetProperty">
  <Key>TravelMode0</Key>
  <Value xsi:type="xs:string">{"name":"Thinning","type":"AUTOMOBILE","description":"","impedanceAttributeName":"WalkTime","timeAttributeName":"WalkTime","distanceAttributeName":"Length","restrictionAttributeNames":["Hallways: Avoid Walls","Hallways: Prefer Middle Med","Hallways: Prefer Center High"],"attributeParameterValues":[{"attributeName":"Hallways: Avoid Walls","parameterName":"Restriction Usage","value":2},{"attributeName":"Hallways: Prefer Middle Med","parameterName":"Restriction Usage","value":0.5},{"attributeName":"Hallways: Prefer Center High","parameterName":"Restriction Usage","value":0.20000000000000001}],"useHierarchy":true,"uturnAtJunctions":"esriNFSBAllowBacktrack","simplificationTolerance":null,"simplificationToleranceUnits":"esriUnknownUnits"}</Value>
</PropertySetProperty>
```

And this seems to be the structure for adding hierarchy attributes to a network template. Could this be potentially copy-pasted with the correct sources to the indoors template XML? I got this from adding a hierarchy attribute in a separate, test network dataset and creating a template from that. It seems that ArcGIS Pro doesn't allow you to add the network attributes fully to an Indoors network dataset.

```xml
<NetworkAssignment xsi:type='typens:NetworkAssignment'>
    <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <NetworkAttributeName>Hierarchy</NetworkAttributeName>
    <NetworkElementType>esriNETJunction</NetworkElementType>
    <NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>{318C4B91-F5D2-467A-996C-0AB51B0D8FF2}</NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>
    <NetworkEdgeDirection>esriNEDNone</NetworkEdgeDirection>
    <NetworkEvaluatorData xsi:type='typens:PropertySet'>
        <PropertyArray xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty'>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Version</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:short'>1</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>ConstantValue</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:int'>0</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
        </PropertyArray>
    </NetworkEvaluatorData>
</NetworkAssignment>
<NetworkAssignment xsi:type='typens:NetworkAssignment'>
    <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <NetworkAttributeName>Hierarchy</NetworkAttributeName>
    <NetworkElementType>esriNETEdge</NetworkElementType>
    <NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>{318C4B91-F5D2-467A-996C-0AB51B0D8FF2}</NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>
    <NetworkEdgeDirection>esriNEDNone</NetworkEdgeDirection>
    <NetworkEvaluatorData xsi:type='typens:PropertySet'>
        <PropertyArray xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty'>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Version</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:short'>1</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>ConstantValue</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:int'>2</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
        </PropertyArray>
    </NetworkEvaluatorData>
</NetworkAssignment>
<NetworkAssignment xsi:type='typens:NetworkAssignment'>
    <IsDefault>true</IsDefault>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <NetworkAttributeName>Hierarchy</NetworkAttributeName>
    <NetworkElementType>esriNETTurn</NetworkElementType>
    <NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>{318C4B91-F5D2-467A-996C-0AB51B0D8FF2}</NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>
    <NetworkEdgeDirection>esriNEDNone</NetworkEdgeDirection>
    <NetworkEvaluatorData xsi:type='typens:PropertySet'>
        <PropertyArray xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty'>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Version</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:short'>1</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>ConstantValue</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:int'>0</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
        </PropertyArray>
    </NetworkEvaluatorData>
</NetworkAssignment>
<NetworkAssignment xsi:type='typens:NetworkAssignment'>
    <IsDefault>false</IsDefault>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <NetworkAttributeName>Hierarchy</NetworkAttributeName>
    <NetworkSourceName>Digitized_Pathways</NetworkSourceName>
    <NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>{68055FC4-37D5-4BD0-81A5-CD177A29759C}</NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>
    <NetworkEdgeDirection>esriNEDAlongDigitized</NetworkEdgeDirection>
    <NetworkEvaluatorData xsi:type='typens:PropertySet'>
        <PropertyArray xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty'>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Version</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:short'>1</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Expression</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>PATHWAY_RANK</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>PreLogic</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:string'></Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
        </PropertyArray>
    </NetworkEvaluatorData>
</NetworkAssignment>
<NetworkAssignment xsi:type='typens:NetworkAssignment'>
    <IsDefault>false</IsDefault>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <NetworkAttributeName>Hierarchy</NetworkAttributeName>
    <NetworkSourceName>Digitized_Pathways</NetworkSourceName>
    <NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>{68055FC4-37D5-4BD0-81A5-CD177A29759C}</NetworkEvaluatorCLSID>
    <NetworkEdgeDirection>esriNEDAgainstDigitized</NetworkEdgeDirection>
    <NetworkEvaluatorData xsi:type='typens:PropertySet'>
        <PropertyArray xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfPropertySetProperty'>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Version</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:short'>1</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>Expression</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:string'>PATHWAY_RANK</Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
            <PropertySetProperty xsi:type='typens:PropertySetProperty'>
                <Key>PreLogic</Key>
                <Value xsi:type='xs:string'></Value>
            </PropertySetProperty>
        </PropertyArray>
    </NetworkEvaluatorData>
</NetworkAssignment>
</NetworkAssignments>
<HierarchyAttributeName>Hierarchy</HierarchyAttributeName>
<HierarchyMaxValues xsi:type='typens:ArrayOfInt'>
    <Int>1</Int>
    <Int>2</Int>
    <Int>2147483647</Int>
</HierarchyMaxValues>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you can copy that bottom XML bit into the proper area in the the Indoors preliminary template and it will use the hierarchy when thinning the pathways.

I'm still unsure why this was necessary to avoid the pathways going through rooms.

The [classify pathways](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/indoors/classify-indoor-pathways.htm) tool was used prior to running the modified thin pathways script, but it only classified pathways as secondary; all pathways that should've been classified as primary were instead null. So I selected all null in that field and calculated them as primary.